# A logical gap in the proof of $\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\alpha+\beta)=\alpha+\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\beta)$

Tags: proof-explanation, ordinals

I found this proof on a notes *CONSTRUCTING THE INTEGERS: $\Bbb N$, ORDINAL NUMBERS, AND TRANSFINITE ARITHMETIC* by Jeremy Booher. You can download freely it [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/22cd/ff3da167259fb6f7909cbe50ee76f3ce6879.pdf).

At page 6, he presents Lemma 28 and its proof:

> [image]

Here is my understanding of his proof.

> - Let $X=\{\gamma\mid\gamma<\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\alpha+\beta)\}$ and $Y=\{\gamma\mid\gamma<\alpha+\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\beta)\}$.
> - Clearly, $\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\alpha+\beta)$ and $\alpha+\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\beta)$ are ordinals. To prove that $\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\alpha+\beta)=\alpha+\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\beta)$, the author intends to show that $X=Y$.
> - For $\gamma\in X$, $\gamma<\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\alpha+\beta)$ and thus $\gamma<\alpha+\beta$ for some $\beta\in A$. Then $\gamma<\alpha+\sup\limits_{\beta\in A}(\beta)$ and thus $\gamma\in Y$. It follows that $X\subseteq Y$.
>
> Clearly, the author has proved that $X\subseteq Y$, but he has NOT proved $Y\subseteq X$. In other words, he has shown that all ordinals less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$ is also less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$, whereas he has done NOTHING in proving the converse direction that all ordinals less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ is also less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$. As a result, he can NOT claim *Therefore the ordinals less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$ and the ordinals less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ are the same*. Thus he has not completed the proof.

---

**My questions:**

1. Is my understanding of his proof correct?
2. How do I proceed to prove that $Y\subseteq X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your understanding, but the remaining part of the proof is just the same thing again:

Let $\gamma < \alpha + \sup_{\beta \in A}\beta$. Then $\gamma < \alpha + \beta$ for some $\beta \in A$. So $\gamma < \sup_{\beta \in A}(\alpha + \beta)$.

Note that really the key thing here is that all the implications are bidirectional - so a more compact proof of both directions at once would result by dropping a couple words and using "if and only if":

$\gamma < \alpha + \sup_{\beta \in A}\beta$ if and only if $\gamma < \alpha + \beta$ for some $\beta \in A$, which holds if and only if $\gamma < \sup_{\beta + A}(\alpha + \beta)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Honestly, the statement $\gamma < \alpha + \sup_{\beta \in A}\beta\implies\exists\beta\in A:\gamma < \alpha + \beta$ is not obvious to me (I don't know how to prove it). Could you please leave me some hints to prove $\gamma < \alpha + \sup_{\beta \in A}\beta\implies\exists\beta\in A:\gamma < \alpha + \beta$?

Comment: Please address my concern in the previous comment! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: By definition of addition. Assuming that $\sup_{\beta \in A}\beta$ is a limit ordinal, the definition of $\alpha + \sup_{\beta \in A}\beta$ is $\bigcup_{\delta < \beta \in A}(\alpha + \delta)$. If $\gamma$ is less than this ordinal, then by the definition of the ordering $\gamma$ is a member of this ordinal, and is therefore a member of $\alpha + \delta$ for some $\delta < \beta \in A$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like to ask if it is true that $$\alpha + \sup_{\beta \in A}\beta=\bigcup_{\delta < \beta \in A}\{\alpha + \delta\}=\bigcup\{\alpha + \delta\mid\gamma<\beta\text{ for some }\beta\in A\}=\bigcup\left\{\alpha + \delta\mid\gamma<\bigcup A\right\}$$